# Rails polymorphic associations, get parent post of comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

There are 3 models: Social, Event, and Comment. Comment is the polymorphic model, of course.
How can I get the Social or Event or Comment from some comment? 
Example I have a comment object with commentable_id:5 and commentable_type: Social, how to get this social from comment object?

Comment: comment.commentable will also work.

Comment: `comment.commentable` try it and this doesn't work;

Comment: It should work, If you have set the configuration correctly.

Comment: yep, sorry check it now and it work, but when try before ask question this is doesn't work. Thanks a lit

Comment: Okey, I have added it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the below...

```
comment.commentable
```